# How to write the PostgreSQL query for "Update Statistics" for a given table?

Tags: postgresql

Example: For MSSQL we use "UPDATE STATISTICS table_name".

What can we use for PostgreSQL?

Comment: You can use:
ANALYZE table_name;

Answer (score 3):

To update the statistics of a table, you use the [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) command.

```
analyze table_name;
```